# Grab Azure resources using a list

Tags: azure, powershell, csv, tags

I am trying to bulk grab Azure resources and change their tags. I have the resource names in a csv file.

```
$List= Import-Csv "C:\Users\8792.csv"
$Resources = (Get-AzResource | Where-Object {$_.Resource.Name -eq $List})
$Resources.Count
foreach ($resource in $resources){

        #$resource.Name
        $rgtags = $resource.Tags
        #depending on the tag to update, enter the removal value below
        #$rgtags.Remove("DepartmentNumber")
        $rgtags.Remove("Manager")
        $rgtags.Remove("DepartmentNumber")
        $rgtags.Remove("ApplicationName")

        #update tag to be added to resource
        #$rgtags += @{DepartmentNumber = "9r30" }
        $rgtags += @{OwnerEmail = "pita@mail.com" }
    
        Set-AzResource -ResourceId $resource.resourceid -Tag $rgtags -Force -AsJob
}
```

Nothing happens when I run this code. What am I missing? Is there another way to do this?

Comment: `$_.Resource.Name -eq $List` should be `$_.Resource.Name -in $List.CSVColumName` for starters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has an issue with the `$List` variable. If you want to check & filter one of the columns in a `.csv` file, you need to filter  `$List` with a specific column  i.e., `$List.ResourceName` instead of filtering the entire `.csv` file.  Due to this conflict, you couldn't able to retrieve any output.

There are two ways to modify your code:

1. Modify `for-each` loop as below:

```
$List= Import-Csv "C:\resourceslist.csv"  
foreach ($resource  in  $List.ResourceName)
{
 $resource = Get-AzResource -Name $resource
 $rgtags = $resource.Tags 
 $rgtags.Remove("Manager")           
 $rgtags.Remove("DepartmentNumber") 
 $rgtags += @{OwnerEmail = "pita@mail.com" }
 Set-AzResource -ResourceId $resource.resourceid -Tag $rgtags -Force -AsJob }
```

*Or*

2. As @Santiago Squarzon suggested, Use *"-in"* `$_.Resource.Name -in $List.ResourceName}` or *"-contains"* `$_.Resource.Name -contains $List.ResourceName}` functions as below:

```
$List= Import-Csv "C:\resourceslist.csv"
$Resources = (Get-AzResource | Where-Object {$_.Resource.Name -contains $List.ResourceName})
$Resources.Count
foreach ($resource in $resources){
        $rgtags = $resource.Tags
        $rgtags.Remove("Manager")
        $rgtags.Remove("DepartmentNumber")
        $rgtags += @{OwnerEmail = "pita@mail.com" }
        Set-AzResource -ResourceId $resource.resourceid -Tag $rgtags -Force -AsJob
}
```

***Output:***

[image]

[image]

*Note:* You can also `update-Aztag` PowerShell command to update the tags of Azure resources.